# undefined method error when pass function from one class to the other

Tags: ruby

I am working on a ruby script where I have two classes: `Logger` and `Test`, where Logger is recording the function name along with its input and output when a function is called.

Then I have Test class where I define a `test_func` to double the input. However, I met an undefined method error when using the `func_logger` function after `logger` is initialized. I guess it is a scope issue so `logger` didn't know where to find `test_func`. If so, which part should I modify to make it work? Thanks in advance.

p.s. I have to maintain the code structure in the way below, so I can't move any function outside a class.

```
class Logger
  def initialize(id)
    @id = id
  end

  def func_logger(func, input)
    func_name = func.to_s
    output = method(func).call(*input)
    {"name"=>func_name, "input"=>input, "output"=>output}
  end
end


class Test
  def initialize(id)
    @id = id
  end
  
  def exec(input)
    def test_func(a)
      a*2
    end
    logger = Logger.new(@id)
    logger.func_logger(:test_func, input)
  end
end

test = Test.new(0)
puts test.exec(2).inspect
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    3: from main.rb:29:in `<main>'
    2: from main.rb:24:in `exec'
    1: from main.rb:8:in `func_logger'
main.rb:8:in `method': undefined method `test_func' for class `Logger' (NameError)
exit status 1
```

Comment: Note that Ruby doesn't have nested methods. Defining`test_func` within `exec` might not work the way you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`method` on `Logger` is equivalent to calling `self.method(...)`, which tries to get a Method instance by looking up a method with the passed name on `self`. There is obviously no `test_func` on the Logger instance. Calling `method` on the *calling* object will produce a Method instance bound to the `Test` instance, which is what you want to pass. This Method instance has a `#name` property, and you can `#call` it with your arguments:

```rb
class Logger
  def initialize(id)
    @id = id
  end

  def func_logger(func, *input, &block)
    output = func.call(*input, &block)
    {"name"=> func.name.to_s, "input"=>input, "output"=>output}
  end
end

class Test
  def initialize(id)
    @id = id
  end

  def exec(input)
    def test_func(a)
      a*2
    end
    logger = Logger.new(@id)
    logger.func_logger(method(:test_func), input)
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks! This works almost perfectly for my case. My one last concern is what if I have an optional parameter in `func_logger`, like `def func_logger(func, *input, &block, type="alpha")`. I know it is not correct syntax, but where I should place that optional parameter here?

Comment: You won't be able to capture default parameters. Unless it's an argument passed to your func_logger, you won't be able to log it. You could do some metaprogramming hackery to hook methods with logged versions, but unless you specifically have the need to do that, I'd suggest against it.

Comment: No, I don’t need to log them. For example, I would need to pass a flag to `func_logger`  where the default value of the flag is `true` and if flag is true I would have an extra step in the `func_logger`. But as you mentioned, it seems I can’t have default parameters here.